# Selenium unable to click button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

there is a button in https://mokivezi.lt/leidiniai called "**Open**" you can see it under catalog image.

It's element is:
`<button data-href="open" aria-label="Open UAB &quot;Makveža&quot; - Pagrindinis Moki-vezi kaininis leidinys">Open</button>`

Using **Python Selenium** and **Edge/Chrome** webdrivers, I am unable to click that button.
I tried switching to different iframe, but still getting attached error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14248\1636534134.py in <module>
----> 1 WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
      2     EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Open']"))
      3 ).click()

~\Anaconda3\envs\webscraping\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     93             if time.monotonic() > end_time:
     94                 break
---> 95         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     96 
     97     def until_not(self, method, message: str = ""):

TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperties::SetProperty [0x00007FF7262B16C2+15186]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF72624A212+827554]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF725F0ED90]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF725F52225]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF725F523AC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF725F8E087]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF725F71F8F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF725F44C3E]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF725F8B513]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF725F71D23]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF725F43B80]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF725F42B0E]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF725F44344]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperties::SetProperty [0x00007FF72612C3B0+182752]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF726000095]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF72618A6EA+42362]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF72618D425+53941]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF7264A8AB3+1456595]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF72625276A+861690]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF726257854+882404]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF7262579AC+882748]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF72626097E+919566]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF40C77AD4+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF436CA371+33]
```

What wrong am I doing ? To click I tried using `WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Open']"))).click()`

Comment: Please [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1185254).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Open` button is inside an iframe. you need to switch to iframe first, in order to access the element.

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`

```
driver.get("https://mokivezi.lt/leidiniai")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src='//view.publitas.com/uab-makveza/pagrindinis-moki-vezi_kedainiu_parduotuve/?publitas_embed=embedded']")))
openButton=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Open']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", openButton)
```

**Browser snapshot:** After clicked on Open button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the element you are trying to click on doesn't exist

The element that displays "Open" is this

```
<button data-href="open" aria-label="Open UAB &quot;Makveža&quot; - Pagrindinis Moki-vezi kaininis leidinys">
    Open
</button>
```

try this possibly

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Open']"))).click()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried this approach.

Comment: the point is that your xpath is wrong

Comment: ok, can you help me and tell which xpath should I use ?

Comment: copy the xpath of the exact element with chrome developer tools/inspect and test it